# Chainlink UpKeep function error , unable to execute automation

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-keepers

I have been trying to learn smart contract automation with Chainlink . Even with the code from official documentation , I've been unable to run the automation . The contracts cannot be verified on etherscan , the error is :
"Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/AutomationCompatible.sol" not found: File import callback not supported"

I have tried using some other versions of these contracts from github , with no success.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running/deploying the contracts locally, you will need to install the contracts via something like: `npm install @chainlink/contracts`

Remix will take care of this for you
[Remix Example](https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/Automation/UpkeepIDConsumerExample.sol)